# loop inductance of half bridge

Tags: transistors, inductor

i have a question for my class but i cannot answer it, any help to understand this question will be more than grateful.

Why it is so important to minimize the commutation loop inductance of a half bridge especially in case of WBG transistors?

Thanks all

Comment: What have you researched and simulated so far?

Comment: it was a question from my teacher i didnt simulate anything...

Comment: You should. And research the subject.

Comment: Which loop are you talking about - the commutation loop or the Gate driver loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When switching a transistor off (or on), the current changes from the transistor to its free-wheeling diode (which is one of the anti-parallel diodes). This causes a voltage-spike due to the loop inductance \$u_{spike} = L_{loop} \cdot \frac{di}{dt}\$ which might be harmful for semiconductors and/or DC link cap. This is obviously the case with a large loop inductance \$L_{loop}\$ and/or high \$\frac{di}{dt}\$, which means fast switching, and which is a typical feature of wind band-gap devices like SiC or GaN.

With the right gate driver settings you can reduce the switching speed to avoid this voltage spike, but lower switching speed will increase switching losses. So better to keep the loop inductance as small as possible.

Comment: thank you so much